# Python: Add value of iteration variable to variable name within for loop

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, variable-names

I have a pandas df with a column (let's say col3) containing a number. These numbers are used in multiple rows and I want to run a function for rows of each number separatly.

So I wrote each number once into an array like this:

```
l = df.col3.unique()
```

Then a for loop is used to run a function for each number:

```
for i in l:
   a,b = func(df[df.col3 == i])
```

So the function gets rows where col3 contains the value of i of each run. The function returns two data frames (a and b in this case).
I need these two returned data frames of each run.

I want to be able to identify them properly. For that I would like to save returned data frames within the loop like this:

First run: a123, b123
Second run a456, b456
Third run: a789, b789

Means the name of the dataframe contains the current value of i.

I already read I should not use global variables for dynamic variable names but do not know how to realize this instead.

Thank you :)

Comment: How do you use these data frames?

Comment: I will compare the results. Why is that important? I just want the current value of i within a run to be part of the names of the two data frames.

Comment: Why is the name of the variables so important? You can use a dict with the col3's value as the key to save the dataframes.

Comment: I need it because if I just call them df1, df2,... then I always need to have a look into them to remember which one contains what data. With the names I would immediatly see which data is in data frame a123. yes, I read about dictonaries but I can't manage to use them properly for my issue. That is why I'm asking this community.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution A (recommended):**

```
dfs = {}

for i in l:
    dfs["a"+str(i)], dfs["b"+str(i)] = func(df[df.col3 == i])
...
```

And then you can use the dataframes like this:

```
func2(dfs["a1"]) # dfs["a1"] represents func(df[df.col3 == i])'s first return.
...
```

**Solution B (not recommended)**

If you absolutely want to use local variables, you need:

```
for i in l:
    locals()["a"+str(i)], locals()["b"+str(i)] = func(df[df.col3 == i])
```

And then you can use the dataframes with their variable names `a1`,`b1` etc.

Comment: Used your first solution and splitted the list afterwards to have separate dataframes like I need it. Thanks a lot! :)